# Appending to two slice with same underlying array, why the result?

Tags: go, append, slice

Here is a code snippet from some Go book.

```golang
func incr(s []int) {
    s = append(s, 0)
    for i := range s {
        s[i]++
    }
}

func main() {
    s1 := []int{1, 2}
    s2 := s1
    s2 = append(s2, 3)

    incr(s1)
    incr(s2)

    fmt.Print(s1, s2) // "[1, 2][2, 3, 4]"
}
```

I don't understand why the result is "[1, 2][2, 3, 4]".

Based on two points from https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#slices:

> Slices hold references to an underlying array, and if you assign one slice to another, both refer to the same array

> If a function takes a slice argument, changes it makes to the elements of the slice will be visible to the caller, analogous to passing a pointer to the underlying array

Here is what I imagined should happen:

1. At first, both s1 and s2's have the same underlying array [1, 2]
2. After appending 3 to s2, the underlying array changed to [1, 2, 3]. But s1 still only see [1, 2]
3. After `incr(s1)`, s1 is appended 0 and all item incremented, resulting s1 into [2, 3, 1]. The appending also changed the underlying array, so s2 now see [2, 3, 1]
4. After `incr(s2)`, s2 is appended 0 and all item incremented, resulting s2 into [3, 4, 2, 1]. The increment also affected underlying array, so now s1 see [3, 4, 2]
5. So the result printed should be [3, 4, 2][3, 4, 2, 1]

I obviously have huge mistake understanding slice in Go. Please tell me where I am wrong. It seems my reasoning is in accord with slice's behavior. (I know appending to an insufficient capacity slice will also reallocate an underlying array, but don't know how to fit it into this).

Comment: note also that you can get access to the whole underlying array using the notation `s1[:cap(s1)]`. In the spec, https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions, it says `For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity cap(a) rather than the length.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's analyze this program step by step:

```
s1 := []int{1, 2}  // s1 -> [1,2]
s2 := s1           // s1, s2 -> [1,2]
```

The next operation is:

```
s2 = append(s2, 3)
```

This *may* allocate a new backing array if the capacity of the underlying array is not sufficient. In this case, it will do that to give:

```
s1 -> [1,2]
s2 -> [1,2,3]
```

Then `incr(s1)` will append a new element to `s1`, increment values, but the resulting slice will not be assigned to `s1` in main, so still:

```
s1 -> [1,2]
s2 -> [1,2,3]
```

`incr(s2)` will do the same, but this time, the backing array has the capacity to hold the appended zero, so the increment operation increments the values, but the new slice is never assigned to `s2` in `main`. So, `s2` still has 3 elements:

```
s1 -> [1,2]
s2 -> [2,3,4]
```

The backing array of `s2` has one more element in it, but `s2` does not include that element.

Comment: Can I sum as this: only when there is sufficient space, function parameter and slice assignment will share the underlying array. And even when sharing inside function, appended element to slice will not be reflected in caller, only modification to elements will be?

Comment: I think that's a convoluted way of looking at it. When you pass a slice to a function, you pass a struct with 3 values: (ptr, len, cap). This struct passed as value, not as a pointer. The struct has a pointer in it to the underlying array. Modifications made to the underlying array will be visible to the caller. Modifications to the struct itself will not be visible to the caller.